# How to add just one single link between two different breeds in Netlogo

Tags: hyperlink, netlogo

I'd love some help creating links in Netlogo.

Essentially I want to add just one single link between two different breeds in Netlogo, with a defined length 'particle-length'. This link needs to be joined to the other breed that is next to it.
At the moment this code creates a volume exclusive set of turtles, with 3 breeds. One is randomly scattered, and the other two are inside a box. I think the initial arrangement of the two different breeds inside the box needs fixing as well so every purple is next to every green. 
Ultimately I want 50 greens(Big) and 50 purples(Small) that are connected with one link (green to purple) with link length of particle-length 1.

Note water-number, Big-number and small-number are defined on a slider with value 50.

Netlogo Code:

```
breed [Bigs Big]
breed [Smalls Small]  
breed  [ waters water ]

to setup
  clear-all

  set particle-length 1.0

  set-default-shape turtles "square"

     ;;To set up the bigs and smalls inside a central box
     ask patches with [ abs (min-pxcor - pxcor) > 22
    and abs (min-pxcor - pxcor) < 23 + floor (sqrt ( Big-number + Small-number ))
    and abs (max-pycor - pycor) > 22
    and abs (max-pycor - pycor) < 23 + floor (sqrt (Big-number + Small-number))]
     [sprout-Bigs 1 [ set color green ] ]

     ;;Now make half of the Bigs into Smalls
    ask n-of Big-number Bigs [ set breed Smalls] 
    ask Smalls [set color violet] 

  ;;randomly makes volume exclusive Waters where there are no Bigs or Smalls
  ask n-of water-number patches with [ not any? turtles-here] 
  [sprout-waters 1 [ set color blue ]]
  ask Bigs with [any? Smalls-on neighbors4] [create-link-with one-of Smalls-on neighbors4]


  reset-ticks
end
```

Comment: This seems like a lot more than one question. Perhaps someone will be willing to help you with all of this at once, but if not, you might try again and ask one question at a time.

Comment: Ok I've sorted one of the problems out, and edited the original question a bit, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that is throwing the error is

ask n-of ( Big-number / 2 ) Bigs [create-link-with one-of Smalls-on neighbors4]

The simple reason is that for at least one of the bigs being asked there are no small on neighbors4`

Changing it to

```
ask n-of ( Big-number / 2 ) Bigs 
[
If any? Smalls-on neighbors4
 [create-link-with one-of Smalls-on neighbors4]  
 ]
```

Will prevent the error but might not be the behavior you want. Alternatively

ask n-of ( Big-number / 2 ) Bigs with[any? Small-on neighbors4][create-link-with one-of Smalls-on neighbors4]